# how to use static in django project

Tags: python, html, css, django, static

Is this not the correct way of making use of Django's static directories in code?

The folder is static/assets/css/style.css

settings.py

```
    STATIC_URL = 'static/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
```

urls.py

```
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from django.conf import settings

    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

base.html

```
    {% load static %}

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/style.css' %}">
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="">Go somewhere</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

style.css

```
    a{
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Comment: Have you included django.contrib.staticfiles in your INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: why adding static to urlpattenrs ?